# GT Trash made my S4 Zoom slower

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

GT Trash Is a free app available on play store. Ever since i installed it and tried deleting the recovery files (erase data for good) or over-writing them, off my sd card and phone storage my phone has become slower in processing. Everthing is just slower. Why? Need help!